# Root-relative-paths are not working on XAMPP Virtual Host

Tags: php, xampp, root, virtualhost, relative-path

I want to be able to use root-relative-paths (ex: /incl/file.php) while developing the website in XAMPP's localhost so that it will work in the same way when I upload it to a webserver. In order to do that, I've set up a Virtual Host within XAMPP. The Virtual Host works fine when I access it with absolute paths (ex: C:/xampp/htdocs/incl/file.php) or pahts without the slash (incl/file.php), but root-relative-paths (/incl/file.php) don't work at all.

I've tried many different configurations of Virtual Host set ups that I found here and on many websites and uninstalling and installing XAMPP. I've also tried to use "\" instead of "/", but the result is the same. I have Windows 10 Pro with the latest XAMPP version installed on it.

This is the Virtual Host set up I am currently employing.

In the hosts file:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       atriero.localhost
```

In the httpf-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory  "C:/xampp/htdocs">
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/subdomains/site"
    ServerName atriero.localhost
    <Directory  "C:/xampp/subdomains/site">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As an example of root-relative-paths that are not working, in my index page I have

```
require "/header.php";
```

which is located on the "site" folder, the same where index.php is located. If I type "header.php" without the slash, it works fine.

There's also in the header.php page the following line

```
include_once '/includes/dbh.inc.php';
```

where the same issue happens, dbh.inc.php is located in the includes folder within the site folder. If I take the slash out the link works fine, but in the way it is writen, with root-relative-path, it doesn't work.

I expect that it is possible to run root-relative-paths with Virtual Host in XAMPP, I assume it would really help in the development of my website and as far as I know it would be the best way to do so.

If for some reason it isn't possible to use root-relative-paths with Virtual Host and if I have to upload my website to the server without the "\" before every path, will it be harmfull in any way to the working of my website?

Thanks in advance.